# Does Pymongo 2.7.1 support aggregation cursor and maxTimeMS?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I've been searching for last 24 hours an answer to a simple question. Does Pymongo 2.7.1 support cursors for aggregation? And if it does then can we set maxTimeMS on that cursor?

If someone knows the answer please let me know.

EDIT:

Below is a small snippet of code which shows a small query I ran on iPython. The return type of this query should have been Cursor Object type and not dict.

```
In [14]: obj = coll.aggregate({'$group': {'_id': '$l', 'n': {'$sum': 1}}})

In [15]: type(obj) Out[15]: dict
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the API documentation?

Retur value of collection.aggregate: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate

Setting maxTimeMS on a cursor: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.max_time_ms

Comment: It is not working on pymongo for me.

Comment: Update the question with your code and include information about what isn't working and any error messages you get